# how to get a data table from JSON Response

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I'm using API in order to get the data. The response is in JSON format. As of now, I've used the below steps.

```
s2 <- GET("https://api2.elasticgrid.com/api/v1/analytics/vendor/partnerengagement/advanced/all") 

char <- rawToChar(s2$content)
```

I'm getting the output as

```
char 

[1] "{\n\t\"data\":  [\n\t\t{\"Entity Type\":\"transfer_fund\",\"Entity ID\":\"136023000000199105\",\"Reference Number\":\"\",\"Transaction Number\":\"6\",\"Transaction Amount (BCY)\":\"INR 2,600.00\",\"Account ID\":\"136023000000000361\",\"Debit or Credit\":\"debit\",\"Transaction Date\":\"15 Apr 2016\",\"Currency Code\":\"INR\",\"Tax ID\":\"\",\"Taxable Amount (BCY)\":\"INR 0.00\",\"Accrual Transaction ID\":\"136023000000199113\",\"Transaction Amount\":\"-INR 2,600.00\",\"Customer ID\":\"\",\"Vendor ID\":\"\",\"Transaction Amount (FCY)\":\"INR 2,600.00\",\"Taxable Amount (FCY)\":\"INR 0.00\",\"Last Modified Time\":\"2016-05-17 09:38:27\",\"Transaction ID\":\"136023000000199107\",\"Reference No.\":\"\",\"Project ID\":\"\",\"Account Name\":\"Petty Cash\",\"Account Type\":\"Cash\"}.....
```

How to convert this into a data table?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to put your code lines in code blocks

Comment: @xwhitelight I didn't get that, If possible can you explain by an example?

Comment: Put your code in triple backticks (```), as I've just edited your post.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't access the address but to read JSON to R object, use the `fromJSON()` function from the `jsonlite` package:

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(char)
```

**Update:**
The file has problems with some special characters. You need to replace them first:

```
char <- gsub("\t", " ", char, fixed = T) # ideally we need to replace tab characters in strings to '\t' but it's not possible to do that since it'd replace tab characters outside strings as well and cause problems
char <- gsub("\\'", "\'", char, fixed = T)
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(char)$data
```

Comment: I'm getting this response 

Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          ,"Reference No.":"07\/04\/2018 ATM WDL","Project ID":"","Acc
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Since I don't have the data, I can't point the error.

Comment: If the data is small, edit your code with full `char` object, or write it to a file and upload if it's large. I'll check

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't upload the file here. I've sent a mail. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @user12490809 Don't copy your R output, I can't recreate character object with it. Use the following lines to write: `fileConn<-file("output.txt"); writeLines(char, fileConn);
close(fileConn)`

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. But in the future, if you want someone to volunteer their time to solve your problem, you need to make it as easy as possible for us.